# How to make a synchronous generator unstable

Tags: generator, load, torque, synchronous

I was try to analyse what factors can affect the stability of synchronous generator .

Let's say  a synchronous generator working in isolation and some loads are connected to it and we have to make it unstable by various methods ,so how many different ways are there to make it unstable ?

To me one of the obvious method is to just keep increasing the torque due to prime mover and after a  value of prime mover torque, synchronous generator will be unstable.

But ,is there any other method so that we can destabilize the generator (e.g changing load or field current etc.)?

Any suggestions would be appreciated !

Comment: In island operation you can only try to confuse the various regulators involved. Voltage and speed. Not much more you can do. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Jeroen3 , I want to know , what conditions (theoretically) can make a Synchronous generator unstable and how to show mathematically .